# Does anyone know what this android emulator call is?

Tags: android-emulator, logging, emulators, https

I've been looking at the network traffic for an Android emulator using mitm proxy.  I have noticed large amounts of traffic going to google's servers.  Does anyone know what this request would carry or a good way to find out?

Had to put the file on my server because it was too big to add to this post.

[android_emulator_post.txt](http://demo.schempc.com/paste/android_emulator_post.txt)

Comment: That's 30k of data, the vast majority of it hex. What do you expect? People reading hexadecimal numbers as if it were English?

Comment: kinda hoping someone from google is on this that knows the endpoint or someone else is familiar with why the heck google would need to send so much log data.  I would bet that most people are using hex interpreters and not reading like english, lol